# find a missing number in a sorted continuous array

Tags: c, arrays

I am looking to solve this problem in other than O(n) complexity. Most of the problems already described here on SO take the numbers in the range [1,n]. In the problem I am trying to solve, the conditions are:-

1. It's a sorted, continuous list of numbers in an array
2. The start of numbers could be from anywhere, not necessarily from 1-n
3. One element is missing in the array. Find that number.

The simple O(n) solution, I came up with is:-

```
int find_missing_num_ls (int arr[], int len)
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i=0; i<len-1;i++) {
        if (arr[i+1] != (arr[i] +1))
            return (arr[i]+1);
    }   

    return -1;
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to find this ?

Comment: Your solution doesn't meet requirement no.2

Comment: I'm pretty sure [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385896/find-the-first-missing-number-in-a-sorted-list) generalizes to handle varying starting points.

Comment: @TimCastelijns it does. The answer above doesnt assume that the start number is 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Take the smallest (first) number of the array, `k`.
2. Perform a binary search.
   If the middle element is smaller than `k + n/2`, you'll need to search in the first half, otherwise in the second. Repeat with half the array, until array size is small enough that the problem becomes trivial.

This should be O(log n).
And if you find the answer is past the last element, it could also be before the first, since we assumed the first was correct.

Comment: this should work. how would you catch situation where there is no element missing.

Comment: That would depend. If the missing value could be the very first or last one, you'll never be sure. If it can't be, you'll eventually find the last element and notice it's still the right value. If you want to know right from the start, just perform a check on the first and last element - if their difference is (n-1) there is no missing number.