# User matching algorithm

Tags: algorithm, redis

So this problem we have users matching to other online users. However it is not just a one to one match. A user is given a selection of 5 other users to choose from, which are then marked as seen and should not be shown again when the user requests for another 5 users to be shown. More people can come online during the process.

The problem is, I want a way for each user to be shown in the selection for other users, with redis but an algorithm is mostly what im looking for. I'm trying to implement this in the fastest way possible, using redis if possible but I can also make calls to the database if it's needed.

My current solution is as follows, hopefully someone will have some tips to improve this from O(N) calls.

So each user needs to have a *seen* set of `user_id`s. We can have a redis list (queue) of `onlineusers`. Where we keep poppping users from the left until we find one that isn't in the user's *seen* set, save it, add to users seen, then push it on the right. Then once we get 5 of those we left push back the ones we left popped off that were already seen.

This is the best I could think of however it is O(N) each time we want to find 5 users for this one user to select from. It's possible (though not likely) that the user has seen a huge amount and is popping off the whole list.

To help understand this better. A naiive approach is to have every single user contain a copy of all online users in the form of a set. So then we simply pop 5 random set members. But this can't work because theres not enough space, and each time a user goes online they'd have to be added to each user's online users. Or deleted when they go offline and those operations are O(N) considering they are done for N users at O(1)

Does anyone have any tips to match users with other users?

Comment: A. MAybe get 20 users each time instead of 5 (if it is common to look through a lot of users then this might cut down on overhead costs). B. Sounds like you need to (worst case scenario) go over all your (online) user list, so it's gonna be `O(n)` in any case. C. to speed things up, you can get the next 5 while the current 5 are being viewed. This might be wasteful in some scenarios, but will give a better user experience.

Comment: @shapiro.yaacov I was hoping it wouldn't be O(N) for each time you wanna get 5 more users. I was devising a way with a sorted set of all user ids, sorted by user id, where each user keeps an index of where they are up to. So on each call they just resume from there to a new person they've never seen until they cycle back to start. That would be an initial O(log N) to resume at that indexx. I gave up on the idea cause I couldn't think of how to evenly distribute it. I thought to start each user at a random index, but I'm worried of the set always growing at the end or middle being overvisited .

Comment: @shapiro.yaacov For now I will go with this option with optimizations, and see if I can get it working until I ever think of a better way to do it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be good to know about which kind of data we are talking about. How many users exist? How many will be online at average? How is the ratio of "seen users" compared to all users (sparse vs. dense)?

**Modification of your algorithm**
Don't pop the first but choose a random element from the set of online users. This should improve balancing and may help with amortized complexity depending on the ratio of these two sets!

**Alternative Algorithm (more structured; still bad worst-case; should be good if sparse *seen*)**

- Keep *seen* as a balanced tree (O(log n) insertion)
- Keep *online* as a balanced tree.
- While not enough users chosen:

  - Search for first gap in *seen* (e.g. [0,1,3,7] -> 2; O(log n) according to [SO-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385896/find-the-first-missing-number-in-a-sorted-list))
  - Search for first user >= gap-value (O(log n))
  - If user < next_gap_neighbor (in example above: 3; next value after picked gap 2)
  - -> pick
  - Else
  - -> add chosen-gap-value *temporarily* (for this moment; model-decision how often to update *online*) to *seen* OR limit search somehow to > chosen-gap-value (O(log n))

Depending on the data, this should work very good if data is huge and *seen* is sparse!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There will be 5,000 users online at average at one time, but I really want to handle scaling if the number increases to 50,000 or even 100,000. In the average case of 5,000 one user will have seen on average 200, max around 500. So yes data is huge and seen is sparse I will definitely have a look at the points you wrote

Comment: I was asking because search-trees add some overhead which needs a lot of data to be worthwile. A famous example: [Fibonacci Heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap#Practical_considerations). Sparseness is a factor which is important to analyze randomized algorithms. In your case, i would assume, that nothing will beat the randomized algorithm (just pick a random user; check if ok; continue) in terms of simplicity & practical performance (there will be faster methods, which will be harder to implement; e.g. incorporating bloom-filters)!

Comment: if I pop a random user from the onlineusers set. That's nice because it is an O(1) operation in redis. However, unlike the case of the list where it chews through a list of every user and repeats, I'm not sure if each user will get an even dsitribution of users in selection. Each user will have its own individual set of `seen`, so when I pop random users, say 20 and then remove the ones the user has already seen, I don't know if in these left over users I'm getting, Some may be picked out many times and some never. Any ideas on the distribution here or is it worth the risk with random?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Every user has his "seen" data. The picking of each user, which will be part of the 5 new users is uniformly distributed. If all user's are online all the time -> the picked users among each user-seen data will be perfectly uniformly distributed. Of course this may change, depending on the dynamics of "online/offline", but this randomized approach will always be better than "pick first" (and most static strats).Question: what do you want? your old approach will pick the same 5 users for each user who queries (if they are querying the first time;at the same time)

Comment: My old approach will pick 5  for the first user who queries, which are  popped from the left and pushed onto right of  redis list (queue). So the 2nd user doesn't pick them too. My question about random is that just say there are user_ids in the onlineusers set from `1` to `200`. Perhaps user  `1` is never chosen cause it's random, and user `55` is chosen many times. I was saying if I repeat iterating over a list in order the first time each user would be chosen once. Then i'm not sure how even it is after that but I'm guessing it would be pretty even. Just wondering about randomness.

Comment: The `random` approach is good actually as it will scale well with `seen` being sparse and data being huge. I just hope it doesn't take too many repeated calls to find a random element if they are all seen. But in almost every practical case this shouldn't ever be a problem. I guess it doesn't really matter to me if one user is never selected by some other user since they are selecting themselves, and thats a different unrelated issue which alerts them to a user and gives them a higher priority